# How do I show this function is monotonically decreasing?

Tags: functions, derivatives, summation

Let $p = $Probability of head on a coin toss ; $p < 0.5$ (biased coin).  $f(k) =$ Probability that heads is the majority from $k$ tosses, where $k$ takes odd values. I want to show that $f(k)$ monotonically decreases with increasing $k$. How do I go about doing this? I know that $$ f(k) = \sum_{i=\frac{k+1}{2}}^k {k \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{k-i}.$$ How do I proceed from here; I don't know how to compute $f'(k)$ from this point..

Comment: Since $f$ is only defined at integers you can't speak of $f'(k)$. Looks like you'll have to do it the old-fashioned way, by showing $f(k+1)<f(k)$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I tried that too, but couldn't conclusively prove that f(k+1) < f(k) because of some of terms.

Comment: @whacka because f only takes odd arguments this should actually be f(k + 2) not f(k+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $g(l,k)={\rm Prob}(l\textrm{ out of first }k\textrm{ are heads})$. Then $f(k)=\sum\limits_{l>k/2}g(l,k)$ and

$$\begin{array}{ll} f(k+1) & \displaystyle =\sum_{l>(k+1)/2}g(l,k+1) \\[5pt] & \displaystyle = \sum_{l>(k+1)/2} \left[p\,g(l-1,k)+(1-p)\,g(l,k)\right] \\[5pt] & \displaystyle = p\sum_{l>(k-1)/2}g(l,k)+(1-p)\sum_{l>(k+1)/2}g(l,k) \\[5pt] & \displaystyle = p\,\underbrace{g(k/2,k)}_{k\textrm{ is even}} + p\,f(k)+(1-p)\,f(k)-(1-p)\,\underbrace{g\left(\frac{k+1}{2},k\right)}_{k\textrm{ is odd}}\end{array}$$

If $k$ is odd then

$$\begin{array}{ll} f(k+1)& =f(k)-(1-p)\,g\left(\frac{k+1}{2},k\right) \\  f(k+2) & = p\,g\left(\frac{k+1}{2},k+1\right)+f(k+1) \\ & = f(k)+p\,g(\left(\frac{k+1}{2},k+1\right)-(1-p)\,g\left(\frac{k+1}{2},k\right).\end{array} $$

Therefore when $k$ is odd:

$$f(k+2)<f(k) \iff f(k+2)-f(k)<0$$

$$\iff p\,g\left(\frac{k+1}{2},k+1\right)-(1-p)\,g\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)<0 $$

$$\iff p\binom{k+1}{\frac{k+1}{2}}p^{(k+1)/2}(1-p)^{(k+1)/2}-(1-p)\binom{k}{\frac{k+1}{2}}p^{(k+1)/2}(1-p)^{(k-1)/2}<0 $$

$$\iff p\binom{k+1}{\frac{k+1}{2}}-\binom{k}{\frac{k+1}{2}}<0\iff p<\frac{\displaystyle \binom{k}{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{\displaystyle \binom{k+1}{\frac{k+1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{2}. $$